# Customizing Visual Studio debugger watch list - autoexp.dat

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, debugging, autoexp.dat

I have a list of characters and I want to see the debug output as full string. For example, I have below node,

```
typedef struct _Node {
    struct _Node next;
    char value;
} Node;
```

and a reference head, like,

```
Node *head; // lets say contents are like "->A -> B -> C -> D -> NULL"
```

Which means actually the list can represent a string "ABCD" now.
I want to see this head value like an string representation in debugger watch. I know [its possible](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2007/04/06/tweaking-autoexpdat-for-custom-types-in-vs2005/) to customize `children, preview, stringview` with modifying `autoexp.dat`, but I cannot figure out how to combine children value with parent nodes representation unto NULL. Anyone could help to write proper expression?

Comment: As of VS2012, the 'natvis' system is preferred over autoexp.dat (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. @MuertoExcobito

Comment: @Sazzad Hissain Khan, What about this issue now? A sample: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2#content, which also shared us useful information about how to create custom view of Native Objects.